# Refuse save if cell contains text

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code, that refuses and cancels to save a workbook if a cell contains a specific text. the code is working fine, but if i want it to refuse saving if some cells in a range contains specific text then it is not working. my code below that is working:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "Fill in a comment" Then
    Cancel = True
    Response = MsgBox("Fill in a comment", vbCritical, "Error!")
End If

End Sub
```

the code that i tried to make it work but its not

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean

 For Each c In Sheet1.Range("A1:A5000")
        If c.Value = "Fill in a comment" Then
             Cancel = True
              Response = MsgBox("Fill in a comment", vbCritical, "Error!")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead rather than looping:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Cancel = Not Sheet1.Range("A1:A5000").Find("Fill in a comment") Is Nothing
    If Cancel Then MsgBox "Fill in a comment", vbCritical, "Error!"

End Sub
```

It uses the `.Find()` method to look for `"Fill in a comment"` and if it isn't `Nothing` then `Cancel` is set to `True`

Then, we test the value of `Cancel` to see if we need to display the message box.

Doing it this way also makes sure that you don't get 500 message boxes if you have `"Fill in a comment"` written in 500 different cells in that range...